# Specifying variables to include using the step function in R

Tags: r, variables, model, pca

I would like to use manually include variables in a PCA model in R to see if my R-Squared would increase. I have used 'scope' for this as written below:

**my_variables <- step(All_Parameters, direction = "both", trace = 1, ~ . + var1 + var3 + var4 + var5 + var6, scope= ~bathymetry + var1 + var2 + var3 + var4 + var5 + var6 + var7 + var8 + var9 + var10 + var11)**

I am not sure if the above is the correct way to do this but wondering how I can specify only variables (var1 + var3 + var4 + var4 + var6) among my 11 variables to see what my R-squared will be.

Comment: what's your dependent variable? Why can't you just fit those to the variables of interest?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.